# Parsing json with jq with negative index not working on Windows

Tags: jq

I am having following output after a `curl` call

```
{"snapshotsForStream":[{"id":24221},{"id":24230},{"id":24274}],"code":null,"message":null}
```

I just want to get the latest snapshot id (24274, in above case) by parsing the output using `jq` on windows. What I tried is as follows: -

```
curl.exe -s --location --request GET "http://myhost:8080/api/v2/streams/stream/snapshots?idType=byName&name=mystream" --header 'Accept:application/json' --user user1:xyz | jq ".snapshotsForStream[-1].id"
```

It is giving me null.
But when I ran same command on a linux machine then it is giving me the correct output as `24274`

So just want to know that whether there is any way to get the last entry of an array through `jq` json parsing.

Comment: Which version of `jq` are you running in Windows?

Comment: ```jq --version``` results ```jq-1.4```

Comment: `jq ".snapshotsForStream | .[length-1].id"` should work with jq-1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing elements [with negative indices](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ArrayIndex:.%5B2%5D) was introduced in `jq-1.5`, you seem to be running a version before that which is really old. See [-1 index doesn't work #1388](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1388)

Consider upgrading to `jq-1.6` the most recent version released. See [jq - Releases](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases)